Creating a new thread in an API in django and calling another API in that thread
I was told that creating a thread for running background tasks will cause problems because in production gunicorn will kill a thread once the response is recieved.
So, if I create a thread and inside that I call another api which is defined in the same app in django, will gunicorn create another thread for this api and thus wait for it to finish processing ?
